# Image in Cocoapods project not loading

Tags: ios, cocoapods, elcimagepickercontroller

I'm using the ELCImagePickerController. When I click on an image in the picker, the selected overlay isn't appearing. This line of code in the library's source returns `nil`.

```
overlayImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Overlay.png"];
```

I've installed the module via CocoaPods. The target for the library has the image included in its resources, but clearly its not being loaded from my main project.

How do I get it to load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dragged the images into the main project's asset catalog.

Not very satisfying, but it works.